# How can I add a CORS rule to an existing s3 bucket by CDK v3 javascript?

Tags: amazon-s3, cors, aws-cdk, aws-cdk-typescript

I could see there is a function called `addCorsRule` under type `Bucket` to add a cors rule to a newly created S3.

I am trying to achieve similar thing for a existing S3 bucket that is not created by me, and it's in another aws account.
The return type of all the finding existing bucket function e.g. `fromBucketAttributes` is `IBucket`. It does not provide a method for add a new cors rule.

I am wondering if there will be a work around to achieve this?

Thank you very much.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_s3.Bucket.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_s3.IBucket.html

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can't currently do that. https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/discussions/23184

Potentially, you could use a CustomResource and the AWS SDK to get it working.